# psql insert into if else

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I want to make it so that when creating a user, the first user receives $ 1000 on the wallet, and the rest - $ 10 (user_id - pk)

I made this request

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, login, balance, encrypted_password) 
select 1, 'login',
case
        when user_id = 1 then (login = 'login', balance= 1000, encrypted_password = 'password')
        else (login = 'login', balance = 10, encrypted_password = 'password')
end as user_id
RETURNING user_id
```

but when I make this request, I get the error:

ERROR: ERROR: column "user_id" does not exist
LINE 4: when @user_id == 0 then (login = 'login', balance= '...
^
HINT: There is a "user_id" column in the "users" table, but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

SQL state: 42703
character: 103

Comment: what's with the @ character?

Comment: I saw this symbol in one staсkoverflow response and decided to add it

Comment: remove it.  that is not valid

Comment: I'm remove this. it's still the same mistake

Comment: You can't use `IF` in SQL, only in PL/pgSQL. But I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You are providing a single row with `user_id = 1` so what is the purpose of the "if"? It can never be the "else" part as it's only one value

Comment: need to make sure that the first registered user has $ 1000 credited to the balance, and those who will create accounts after - $ 10

Comment: In case you are not sure how to insert with IF/ELSE (as it only works in pgSQL). You can INSERT then UPDATE.